# Calculating pandas DataFrame column which is equal to the missing words from one set to another in a previous DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, set, difference

I need some tips to make a calculation.

My dataframe looks like the following:

```
text_id     name     date                words
1           John     2018-01-01          {ocean, blue}
1           John     2018-02-01          {ocean, green} 
2           Anne     2018-03-01          {table, chair}
3           Anne     2018-03-01          {hot, cold, warm}
3           Mark     2018-04-01          {hot, cold}
3           Ethan    2018-05-01          {warm, icy}
4           Paul     2018-01-01          {cat, dog, puppy}
4           John     2018-02-01          {cat}
5           Paul     2018-03-01          {cat, sheep, deer}
```

In the text, the `text_id` stands for an specific text (**SAME TEXT_ID = SAME TEXT**). The `name` column stands for the person that has edited the text. The `date` column stands for the date in which the user made the edit. The `words` column is composed by the words that form the text after the users edit.

**The `words` column is a set**. I need to add an aditional column, `erased_words`, which contains the set difference of the current edit (in the current row) and the previous one (in the previous row) on **THE SAME** text. This probably means the operation must be done grouping by `text_id`.

The sample output here would be:

```
text_id     name     date          words            erased_words
1           John     2018-01-01    {ocean,blue}     {}
1           John     2018-02-01    {ocean,green}    {blue}
2           Anne     2018-03-01    {table,chair}    {}
3           Anne     2018-03-01    {hot,cold,warm}  {}
3           Mark     2018-04-01    {hot,cold}       {warm}
3           Ethan    2018-05-01    {warm,icy}       {hot, cold}
4           Paul     2018-01-01    {cat,dog,puppy}  {}
4           John     2018-02-01    {cat}            {dog, puppy}
5           Paul     2018-03-01    {cat,sheep,deer} {}
```

Note that basically, the `erased_words` column contains the set difference among the words column in row `i-1` and words column in row `i`, **only if the text_id in row i and row i-1 is the same**, because: I only want the words missing among consecutive editions in the SAME text (same `text_id`), not different ones.

Any tips on this will be extremely helpful.

**EDIT**:

In order to turn the `words` column into a set, do:

```
df['words'] = df['words'].str.strip('{}').str.split(',').apply(set)
```

**NOTE:**

This isn't a duplicated question, I made a similar one, but note that the calculation I wanted to do was completely another.

**Please, I still didn't get a correct answer. Any help will be really really appreciated**

Comment: can you just provide the code to recreate the dataframe sample you gave ? It takes to to always copy and print the table, erase spaces and add the quotes and everything

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes of the question I have assumed that your `text_id` column is not the index of your dataframe, but even if it is then just call `reset_index()` before doing the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"text_id": [1, 1, 2],
                  "name": ["John", "John", "Anne"],
                  "date": ["2018-01-01", "2018-02-01", "2018-03-01"],
                  "words": [{"ocean", "blue"}, {"ocean", "green"}, {"table", "chair"}]})

df["word history 1"] = df["words"].shift(1).fillna(pd.Series([set()]))
df["erased words"] = df["word history 1"] - df["words"]

idx = df.groupby("text_id").head(1).index
df.loc[idx, "erased words"] = df.loc[idx, "erased words"].apply(lambda x: set())
df.drop("word history 1", axis=1, inplace=True)
```

So in essence, I've created a `history` column that has a delay of 1 for each of the rows in the original `words` column. You'll end up with:

```
df
    text_id  name   date        words           erased words
0   1        John   2018-01-01  {blue, ocean}   {}
1   1        John   2018-02-01  {green, ocean}  {blue}
2   2        Anne   2018-03-01  {chair, table}  {}
```

Comment: @HRDSL With creating the extra `word history 1` column? That shouldn't create that big of a problem in terms of efficiency. How big is your data set?

Comment: I'm using it with different datasets, but the biggest could have more than 1000000 rows and 9 columns.

Comment: @HRDSL See how long it takes to run on your largest data set. I don't think that there is much that can be improved upon in terms of efficiency however.

Comment: I need to calculate the size of the erased_words set. when i do: df['number_erased_words] = df['erased_words'].apply(len), it returns this error: object of type 'float' has no len(). Is there a way of correcting this?

Comment: Ok there must be some `Nan` values in the `erased_words` column now. I've slightly edited my solution above - try and see if the new `df["words"].shift(1).fillna(pd.Series([set()]))` line for creating `df["word history 1"]` helps. If not, do `df['erased words'].fillna(pd.Series([set()]), inplace=True)` before applying your `len` function.

Comment: Hi! I'm running some tests with the code that you provided and it appears that there are some incorrect values. For instance, in the first appereance of a page, the erased words column would always be {}, but in my tests this doesn't happen. Can you double check your answer, please?